# Finding the slope of a line perpendicular to a line of reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

While working on a problem where I am reflecting a point across an arbitrary line through the origin my TA gave me the equations $(y+b)/2=m(x+a)/2$ and $(b-y)/(a-x)=(-1/m)$ where (x,y) is the given point and (a,b) is the reflected point.  What exactly are these equations and how are they related?

Answer (score 0):

Q1. If L is that arbitrary line (that passes through the origin and has slope m), what is the equation of L?

Q2. If H is another line that is perpendicular to L, what is the slope of H (in terms of m)? How is this slope related to (x, y) and (a, b)?

Q3. What is so special about the point that L and H intersect?